# BlueZ: Method "Connect" with signature "s" on interface "org.bluez.Network1" doesn't exist

Tags: bluetooth, dbus, bluez

I thought that when I started the Bluetooth daemon the D-Bus interface ***org.bluez.Network1*** would be created along with the ***Connect*** method. I've cloned, built, and installed the latest&greatest BlueZ (v5.45) from GitHub which comes with a suite of Python test scripts. When I run ***test-network***:

```
# ~/b/test> ./test-network B8:27:EB:F7:E4:50 panu
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./test-network", line 42, in <module>
    iface = network.Connect(service)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 70, in __call__
    return self._proxy_method(*args, **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Connect" with signature "s" on interface "org.bluez.Network1" doesn't exist
```

When I try to build a network interface on the client side using ***bt-pan***, I get:

```
~# /usr/bin/bt-pan client --wait B8:27:EB:00:D4:35
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bt-pan", line 237, in <module>
    if __name__ == '__main__': sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/bt-pan", line 209, in main
    try: iface = net.Connect(opts.uuid)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 145, in __call__
    **keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 651, in call_blocking
    message, timeout)
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Connect" with signature "s" on interface "org.bluez.Network1" doesn't exist
```

How do I create the D-Bus interface ***org.bluez.Network1*** along with ***Connect***?

BTW, shouldn't ***org.bluez.Network1*** come "*in the box*" with BlueZ, so to speak?

Comment: `org.bluez.Network1` belongs to the device interface. When you connect a new device which has the network tethering capability with your adapter, then you will see this interface after connecting the network profile.

Comment: To clarify: the `org.bluez.Network1` interface will only be implemented on the D-Bus object which represents the device which provides that network capability. See the [API documentation](https://github.com/r10r/bluez/blob/master/doc/network-api.txt).